# Is in-app purchase still exists on the device if buyer's account is logged out?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, in-app-purchase

Background : 
I want to buy the full version of Cytus and Deemo games using my friend's credit card, so what I thought is he have to login using his google account and then after purchasing is complete, he logged out his account.

My question : 
Is the purchase still saved on my device even if my friend account already logged out of my device? And is it possible to restore the purchase again if someday I reinstall the games after I delete it?

Thank you.

Comment: If possible, ask him to register his credit card on your Google account, then buy the apps under his supervision (and also the song packs, in case you want to play them later), then unregister his credit card again. Otherwise, buy Google Play gift vouchers if it's available in your country.

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes, I thought that was the best solution too after I read Maxime answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged in with your Google account, the app will be in the list of all your apps and you will be able to re-install it on any device conected to your Google account.

Comment: In case I log two accounts when purchasing. First is mine, second is my friend's. Then use my friend's account to buy the games and then log out my friend's account. which account is connected to the apps purchase history? my friend's or mine or both?

Comment: The purchase will be related to the account that did the purchase, so if you buy something with your friend's account, the purchase will be related to his account.

Comment: so if I want to reinstall the game after I delete it, I need to login using my friend's account, is that it? Can you provide reliable sources of how this works?

Comment: Yes you'll have to be logged with your friend's account, I have no sources, but I bought an app 1 year ago with my Galaxy s3 and re-instaled it on my Note4 1 week ago.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments in another answer, any purchase made through the Google Play Store (or the Amazon App Store) is tied to the account that made the purchase. Your friend's account bought the game, not yours.